# Need help creating a view

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
CREATE VIEW custowner
AS
   (SELECT        
        RTRIM(p.FirstName)+ ' ' + p.LastName AS [name], 
        LEFT(p.Phone, 12) AS phone, 
        p.CellPhone AS cellphone, 
        LEFT(p.EMail, 22) AS email
    FROM  
        CUSTOMER_OWNER co 
    INNER JOIN 
        PEOPLE p ON co.PeopleID = p.PeopleId
    ORDER BY 
        name ASC);
```

I get an error:

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

How can I fix this?

Comment: From the error, I am guessing that you are using Microsoft SQL Server not MySQL. Please change the tag accordingly,

Comment: I love how the error tells you exactly whats wrong and you don't try changing that.

Comment: How will you use that view if PeopleID isn't included in the columns? You should also adopt a naming convention for views so you know that it is a view e.g. `create view custowner_v`

Comment: @Used_By_Already Good point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution here is to remove `order by` clause from your query. If you want to display results in particular order of `name`, you can do that while selecting data from view.

Comment: Thank you @Harshil,  I forgot you cannot use order by clause in a create view statement

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do it, but you should probably follow advise to order it on a view. 
However to hack it you can use TOP 100 PERCENT in your SELECT statement

```
create view custowner
as
(SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT     
rtrim(p.FirstName)+ ' ' + p.LastName as [name], 
left(p.Phone, 12) as phone, 
p.CellPhone as cellphone, 
left(p.EMail, 22) as email
FROM CUSTOMER_OWNER co INNER JOIN PEOPLE p
ON co.PeopleID = p.PeopleId
order by name ASC);
```

It should work now